# Optimize Recursive Function to traverse nested DOM nodes

Tags: javascript, optimization, recursion, dom

I wrote a recursive function that traverses nested DOM nodes of the following form:

```
<a href="#" title="test">
    <div id="nested-image">
          <img src="image.jpg" />
    </div>
</a>
```

The recursive function is the following:

```
function getNestedNodes(node) {
var ary = [];
for(var i = 0; i < node.length; ++i) {
    var myJSONChildren = {};
    if(node[i].childElementCount) {
        var myNode = node[i].children;
        for(var j = 0; j < myNode.length; ++j) {
            for(var k =0, attrs = myNode[j].attributes, l = attrs.length; k < l; ++k) {
                myJSONChildren['tag'] = myNode[j].nodeName;
                myJSONChildren[attrs.item(k).nodeName] = attrs.item(k).nodeValue;
            };
        }
        myJSONChildren['children'] = getNestedNodes(myNode); //Recursive Call
        ary.push(myJSONChildren);
    };
}
return ary;
}
```

so if I call that function this way:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
getNestedNodes(node);
```

it returns a JSON array of the following form:

```
[{
  tag:'a',
  href:"#,
  title:"test",
  children:[{
             tag:"div",
             id:"nested-image",
             children:[{
                        tag:"img",
                        src:"image.jpg"
                       }]
             }]
  }]
}]
```

However, I think that my function is way too complex, and I know that there must a better way to get the same results.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Since the DOM is essentially a tree... I'd suggest checking out some tree traversal algorithms. This wikipedia page provides some recursive traversal pseudocode algorithms: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal And these jQuery functions should help too: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

Answer (score 4):

Note that when you do `document.querySelectorAll` you are getting not a single node but a list of nodes. This seems to be causing confusion because your function refers to `node.length` - but a single node does not have any length property. Your original function also does not seem to behave exactly as you want it to in that it excludes the parent node (`a` in your example).

If you ensure that you are passing the function a single node, then it can indeed be simplified a lot:

```
function getTree(node) {
    var r = {tag: node.nodeName}, a, i;
    if (node.childElementCount) {
        r.children = [];
        for (i = 0; a = node.children[i]; i++) {
            r.children.push(getTree(a));
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; a = node.attributes[i]; i++) {
        r[a.nodeName] = a.nodeValue;
    }
    return r;        
}
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
console.log(getTree(links[0])); // only pass the first node to the function
```

[(JSfiddle here)](http://jsfiddle.net/gpk3T/2/)